# Guidance on unit testing REST call in controller returning a promise

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, rest, promise, ngresource

I'm able test - $scope.dvModel = DienstverlenerDetailService.query(); - accordingly. I cant figure out how to test the commented-out lines. Sure could you use some guidance on that.

```
angular.module('dvb.controllers').controller('ServiceFacilitatorEditController', ['$scope', 'DienstverlenerDetailService', function(

    $scope, 
    DienstverlenerDetailService) {
    'use strict';

    $scope.dvModel = DienstverlenerDetailService.query();

    /*DienstverlenerDetailService.query().$promise.then(
        function(response) {
            $scope.dvModel = response.data;
        },
        function(error) {   

        }
    );*/
}]);



describe('serviceFacilitatorEditController', function() {
    'use strict';

    beforeEach(module('dvb.ui'));

    var scope, ctrl, fact, json, $rootScope, $compile, $controller, $injector;

    beforeEach(function() {
        inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_, _$controller_, _$injector_) {
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $compile = _$compile_;
            $controller = _$controller_;
            $injector = _$injector_;
        });

        jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/src/main/webapp/stubs/';
        var f = readFixtures('servicefacilitator_0');
        json = JSON.parse(f);

        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        var DienstverlenerDetailService = { query: function() {} };
        spyOn(DienstverlenerDetailService, 'query').and.returnValue(json);
        ctrl = $controller('ServiceFacilitatorEditController', {
            $scope: scope,
            DienstverlenerDetailService: DienstverlenerDetailService
        });
    });

    it('it should....', function() {
        expect(scope.dvModel.data).toBe(json.data);
    });
});
```

Looked at a couple of other posts where $q was used, $rootscope.apply() and/or other things to resolve the promise, however I cant seem to glue it together. I grasp the concept but still feel strange that that 1 single line is able to test perfectly but the other notation isnt.

The main reason for me asking this is:
1 - I want to understand
2 - I cant just put the promise on $scope.vdModel, i need whats inside the data property wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you spy on `DienstverlenerDetailService`'s `query` method. Return an object with the property `$promise` with value as a promise, you can use `$q.when`. Inject `$q` service as well.

```
     spyOn(DienstverlenerDetailService, 'query').
                       and.returnValue({$promise:$q.when(json)});
```

And in your expectation do:-

```
it('it should....', function() {
    scope.$digest(); //<-- Apply digest for the promise to be resolved.
    expect(scope.dvModel.data).toBe(json.data); //<-- Now set the expectation
});
```

Just to add on, when you create a mock service you can probably do it in a different was as well (I generally prefer), instead of creating an anonymous function to be spied upon, you could create mock object using `jasmine.createSpyObj` and add any number of methods on the mock that you may want to test.

```
  DienstverlenerDetailService = jasmine.createSpyObj('DienstverlenerDetailService', ['query']);

  DienstverlenerDetailService.query.and.returnValue({$promise:$q.when(json)});
```

Similarly if you have to mock other methods as well you could do:-

```
 DienstverlenerDetailService = jasmine.createSpyObj('DienstverlenerDetailService', ['query', 'save', 'delete', ...etc]);

 //And set return value for specific methods...
```

Comment: @SanJayFalcon You are welcome.. I have updated with another technique to create mock as well..