# How does one program PhantomJS to wait for AngularJS $resource to resolve before attempting test on returned data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs

I have an AngularJS controller test script using PhantomJS.  The test looks to see if the controller has loaded "users" data from a database via a RESTFul web service using AngularJS' $resource service.  The problem is that the test fails because the $resource (which returns a promise I believe) isn't resolved yet when the test executes.  What's the proper way to deal with this delay so that the test will pass?  Here is my code:

**CONTROLLER**:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Users) {
    $scope.users = Users.query();
    $scope.sortField = 'lastName';
    $scope.reverseSort = true;
})
```

**SERVICE**:

```
angular.module('clearsoftDemoApp').factory('Users', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/ClearsoftDemoBackend/webresources/clearsoft.demo.users', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });
});
```

**TEST**:

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

// load the controller's module
beforeEach(module('clearsoftDemoApp'));

var MainCtrl, scope;

// Initialize the controller and a mock scope
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: scope
    });
}));

it('should retrieve a list of users and assign to scope.users', function () {
    expect(scope.users.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
});
});
```

Comment: Are you doing e2e test or unit test? If you are looking at the unit test you would just mock out your service, when testing the controller. I had provided an answer a little earlier.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142558/guidance-on-unit-testing-rest-call-in-controller-returning-a-promise/26142901#26142901

Comment: I'm trying to do e2e.  Not sure i understand the solution you referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock the factory call and pass the mock to the controller:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    var users = { query: function() { return [{}]; } };
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        Users: users
    });
}))
```

Comment: Thanks, i made that change and now i get this error in the test output:  PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) Controller: MainCtrl should retrieve a list of users and assign to scope.users FAILED
 Error: Unexpected request: GET http://localhost:8080/ClearsoftDemoBackend/webresources/clearsoft.demo.users
 No more request expected
     at $httpBackend (/Users/John/NetBeansProjects/ClearsoftDemo/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1179)
     at sendReq (/Users/John/NetBeansProjects/ClearsoftDemo/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8181)        Expected 0 to be greater than 0.

Comment: Sorry I think I was updating my original answer and you've taken the old one! Have another look and give it go now.

Comment: Where does $q come from?  I'm getting "undefined" on that.

Comment: Sorry - re-edited. It's getting late in the day for me!

Comment: Now i'm getting this:  "Controller: MainCtrl should retrieve a list of users and assign to scope.users FAILED
 Expected undefined to be greater than 0."

Comment: Arrgh! I've updated again! This time it will work - then I'm going to bed.

Comment: Thanks, this passes the test.  But, whats the point of a test like this if it isn't really calling the service?  I guess i'm not really sold on this sort of automated testing in general.  All we're doing is adding more code to manage (the test code) and we have to mock up a service.  All we are really testing is that we can add an empty array to a variable and then test that it worked.  It seems pointless.

Comment: You are testing that your controller interacts with the service as you are expecting, and is dealing with the result correctly. You should test the factory separately.

Comment: What's the difference between this mock-up and the $httpBackend approach?

Comment: By mocking the service you are keeping the tests for each unit (controller & service) separated. This keeps your tests simple and focussed. Save using the $httpBackend mock for when testing your service. If you want to test the two things together then sure, use $httpBackend - but your tests will not be focussed. This will become a problem as your controller grows and interacts with more dependencies, which in turn may have dependencies and so on... It's better to stub dependencies and focus on testing one unit.

Comment: I've screwed something up and i get "Controller: MainCtrl should retrieve a list of users and assign to scope.users FAILED
 TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Users.findAll()')
     at /Users/John/NetBeansProjects/ClearsoftDemo/app/scripts/controllers.js:21".  Here is the test code:  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
        var users = {query: function () {
                return [{}];
            }};
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            Users: users
        });
    }));